# nodejs mongodb check a range against a single value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have some documents as following in db:

```
User A:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1ec1869ea3e213cc2a159e"),
    "age": 27,
    "gender": "male",
    "preference": {
        "ageGroup": "25-35",
        "gender": "female"
    }
}

User X:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("378ec1869ea3e212333a159e"),
    "age": 27,
    "gender": "female",
    "preference": {
        "ageGroup": "20-30",
        "gender": "male"
    }
}
```

I am trying to filter docs based on :

- other users' profile `age` and `gender` must match against the user's preference.
- other users' preference also must match against the user's profile `age` and `gender`.

Here's what I am trying:

```
const getGsaMatches = async function (currentUser) {
const user: any = await User.findOne({ _id: currentUser._id });
const userPreference = user.preference;

const ageRange = userPreference.ageGroup.split("-");
const minAgeRange = ageRange[0];
const maxAgeRange = ageRange[1];

const matchResponse: any = await User.find({       
    "gender": userPreference.gender,
    "age": { $gte: minAgeRange, $lte: maxAgeRange },

    "preference.gender": user.gender,
    "preference.ageGroup": user.age, // I'm stuck here
    _id: { $ne: currentUser._id }
});
return matchResponse;
```

}

`preference.ageGroup` contains value in `25-30` string format.

How can I store this field so that it can be compared against a given single `integer` value?

I hope I made the problem clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to start is to actually store it as an Integer. If you're using Mongo v4.0+ you can also use [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) but if this is a query you're doing often then you might aswell save it in a structure like:

```
ageGroup: {
   min: 20,
   max: 30,
   value: "20-30"
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
const matchResponse: any = await User.find({
    _id: { $ne: currentUser._id },
    "gender": userPreference.gender,
    "age": { $gte: minAgeRange, $lte: maxAgeRange },

    "preference.gender": user.gender,
    "preference.ageGroup.min":  {$lte: user.age},
    "preference.ageGroup.max":  {$gte: user.age}
});
```

Assuming you don't want to change the structure then you'll have to use an aggregation with `$toInt` as I suggested like so:

```
const matchResponse: any = await User.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            tmpAgeField: {
                $map: {
                    input: {$split: ["$preference.ageGroup", "-"]},
                    as: "age",
                    in: {$toInt: "$$age"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: { $ne: currentUser._id },
            "gender": userPreference.gender,
            "age": { $gte: minAgeRange, $lte: maxAgeRange },
            "preference.gender": user.gender,
            "tmpAgeField.0":  {$lte: user.age},
            "tmpAgeField.1":  {$gte: user.age}
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: which approach would you suggest?

Comment: If it's not too hard to restrucrue the data then I would recommend to do it, ultimately if it doesn't phase you to work around the string structure then it's so bad, but queries like this one will always struggle and you'll never be able to use an index to support it.

Comment: thanks.I'd restructure it.. btw why `ageGroup.value`? any purpose to it?

Comment: No, I just kept the original structure in case you use it else where but you can just drop it